# Autocomplete com imagem e texto

Tags: android

Gostaria de fazer um **AutoComplete no Android** (java/ android studio) com texto e imagem, então achei um site que mostra um exemplo bem prático de como fazer, Eu testei e funcionou perfeitamente porem infelizmente eu não quero carregar as imagens a partir de resource drawable como está no exemplo, Eu gostaria de colocar as imagens por bitmap que são as imagens que capturo por url, sendo assim gostaria de inserir por bitmap porem infelizmente já procurei no google e até agora não consegui achar uma solução, inclusive aqui tem 2 post de uma pessoa perguntando a mesma coisa porem aparentemente não teve a solução, Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Obrigado.

Obs URL: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o melhor para solucionar o seu problema, seria voce por as imagens na pasta assets, que sempre é melhor se essa pasta for criada em "../app/main/assets", no meu caso, eu uso essa função abaixo para pegar as imagens da pasta assets, preencher uma lista com elas e processa-las como quero:

```
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> getImages(Context c) {
    String[] _List;
    String[] files = new String[0];
    ArrayList<Bitmap> result = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    // abre a pasta assets usando AssetManager
    AssetManager assetManager = c.getAssets();
    try {
        // "myfolderimages" é uma pasta na minha pasta assetes
        // aqui eu preciso inverter a ordem delas segundo o criterio "wH"
        // nessa linha eu preencho uma lista com os nomes dos arquivos na pasta
        _List = c.getAssets().list("myfolderimages");
        files = wH.equals("S") ? _List : display.reverseList(_List);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (files != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            InputStream open = null;
            try {
                // nesta linha eu preencho o array com as imagens contidas na lista de nomes
                open = assetManager.open("myfolderimages/" + files[i]);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
                result.add(RotateBitmap(bitmap, 30.0f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (open != null) {
                    try {
                        open.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    // retorna o array com as imagens
    return result;
}
```

Dai eu uso ela assim:

```
// ...
List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
// ...
LinearLayout meuLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
images = getImages(context);
// ...
ImageView minhaImagem = new Imageview(this);
minhaImagem.setImageBitmap(images.get(10);
meulayout.addview(minhaImagem);
setcontentview(meulayout);
```

isso é só um exemplo, adapite ele conforme a sua necessidade

espero que ajude

Comment: Opa, Muito Obrigado pela atenção mas não é isso que eu preciso, Eu já tenho as imagens em array bitmap, eu preciso colocar no autocomplete as imagens ... Nesse link acima tem exatamente o que eu quero fazer porem ele está inserindo as imagens por resource drawable eu tenho o array bitmap e quero inserir a partir do bitmap, pois serão imagens que irei receber da url.

Comment: ok, entaum, mas pegar as imagens do array e converter elas para drawable é o mesmo que pegar imagens por resource drawable

Comment: Eu já tentei desta forma, convertando as imagens a drawable e mesmo assim não funcionou pois no "put" ali ele carrega as imagens por resource e não drawable ... No link o exemplo mostra as imagens em drawable porem em resource por isso mesmo convertando não funciona!.

Comment: posta teu codigo pra eu olhar